# Деление чисел на ассемблере при помощи SSE

Tags: деление, winapi, ассемблер

Пожалуйста подскажите, как поделить два числа на ассемблере при помощи SSE и результат деления вывести на экран.
Я пытался что-то написать, но ничего не получилось.
Вот код:

```
.686
.model flat, stdcall
.XMM
 option casemap:none
 include \masm32\include\windows.inc
 include \masm32\include\kernel32.inc
 include \masm32\include\user32.inc
 includelib \masm32\lib\user32.lib
 includelib \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib

 .data
 op_1 dword 1
 op_2 dword 5
 format byte '%d', 0
 res dword ?
 buf dword ?

 .code
 start:
      mov eax, op_1
      mov edx, op_2
      cvtsi2ss XMM0, eax
      cvtsi2ss XMM1, edx
      divss XMM0, XMM1
      movss [res], XMM0

      invoke wsprintf, addr buf, addr format, res
      invoke MessageBox, NULL, addr buf, NULL, MB_OK
      invoke ExitProcess, 0
 end start
```